# Custom EL functions won't be loaded because no ObjectWarpper was specified

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

My web-application uses Spring MVC and Freemarker. When it must first render a web page (using Freemarker 2.3.22) after starting up, it logs a warning message:

```
 Custom EL functions won't be loaded because no ObjectWarpper was specified
```

(Yes, `ObjectWarpper`; the error message has  typo)

However, I think I *do* have an `ObjectWrapper` specified in my configuration bean:

```
 <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="freemarkerSettings">
       <props>
          <prop key="url_escaping_charset">UTF-8</prop>
          <prop key="object_wrapper">DefaultObjectWrapper(2.3.22)</prop>
       </props>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

So what must I do to correctly set up an `ObjectWrapper` and prevent this warning message being logged?

I have the same problem if I use a `default` `object_wrapper`.

Answer (score 7):

This problem also bothered me, I checked the source code of the org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer class and found the taglibFactory inited without ObjectWrapper being set.

So I extend the FreeMarkerConfigurer class and override the getTaglibFactory() method and replace the spring mvc config. Here is my code:

```
public class DefaultFreeMarkerConfigurer extends FreeMarkerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public TaglibFactory getTaglibFactory() {
        TaglibFactory tagLibFactory = super.getTaglibFactory();
        if (tagLibFactory.getObjectWrapper()==null) {
            tagLibFactory.setObjectWrapper(super.getConfiguration().getObjectWrapper());
        }
        return tagLibFactory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `TagLibFactory` doesn't start out with an `Objectwrapper`. This seems to work:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomFreemarkerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TaglibFactory taglibFactory(ServletContext servletContext) throws IOException, TemplateException {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig = configFreeMarkerConfigurer(servletContext);

        TaglibFactory taglibFactory = freemarkerConfig.getTaglibFactory();
        taglibFactory.setObjectWrapper(freemarker.template.Configuration.getDefaultObjectWrapper(freemarker.template.Configuration.getVersion()));

        return taglibFactory;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That warning message means that no `ObjectWrapper` was specified to the `freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory`. Certainty Spring instantiates `TaglibFactory` itself, but doesn't call `TaglibFactory.setObjectWrapper`, which was only added in FreeMarker 2.3.22, together with the EL function support.