# Intellij idea spring boot launcher: taglibs doesn't load in freemarker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, freemarker

I have web app which is launched on the spring boot 2.0.4.
Dependencies also exists taglibs-standard-impl 1.2.5.
My project structure is as follows.

```
web/
├── src
   ├── main
   │   ├── java
   │   │   
   │   ├── resources
   │   │   ├── i18n
   │   │   ├── static
   │   │   └── templates
   │   └── webapp
   │       ├── META-INF
   │       └── WEB-INF
   └── test
       └── java
```

In WEB-INF i have folder tld with one custom tld.
My main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class WebMain extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebMain.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

The problem is the following and basically it affects the development time. In my main freemarker template i include taglibs, for example:

```
<#assign form=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"]/>
<#assign spring=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags"]/>
<#assign common = JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/tld/common.tld"]>
```

And the problem is that when running in the intellij IDEA via the spring boot launcher, these taglibs can not boot correctly.
If I deploy war in Tomcat or run directly without intellij like java -jar web.war, all is well, taglibs is loaded.

As I understood when debugging, the problem is that it can not find the WEB-INF folder in **TaglibFactory** class if it uses the spring boot launcher of IntellijIdea. In it, any calls caused through

```
servletContext.getResourcePaths (path);
```

where path starts with "/WEB-INF", always return null and accordingly nothing can not be loaded to tldLocations.
Intellij have 4 types shorten command lines: none, JAR manifest, classpath file and user-local-default: none.
I tried to use them all, but everything also remained.
For example, JAR manifest generate command like like this:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:40359,suspend=y,server=n -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -javaagent:/home/birthright/IDEA/lib/rt/debugger-agent.jar=file:/tmp/capture128.props -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /tmp/classpath1030746450.jar com.birthright.WebMain
```

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: I guess it's the same as when running a Spring Boot application directly from `jar`. `src/main/webapp` is not included in it, unlike when you build a `war`. So certainly nothing can load anything from `src/main/webapp` when you start the application from the IDE, as it's not in the classpath, nor is its content visible through the `ServletContext` as resources. Is that right?

Comment: @ddekany Right. In _TaglibFactory.get(String tagliburi)_ method he tries to load the tld location in line _TldLocation explicitlyMappedTldLocation = getExplicitlyMappedTldLocation(taglibUri);_ line , but always return null and later throw **TaglibGettingException**. And yes, if i build jar and launch via java -jar web.jar I get the same error, with war all good.

Comment: Standalone (jar) Spring Boot allows you to put things into `src/main/resources/static/` (and some more: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot), instead of `src/main/webapp`. I assume it also exposes those resources as `ServletContext` resources. But, then maybe it won't work when you deploy it as war...

Comment: Another interesting possibility is that if the application detects that you have requested that via a system property (I mean for example with that), then it tweaks the `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` to add `webapp` as servlet context resource root. You can find an example of adding a resource root here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8525. As it's done optionally, it wouldn't interfere with war deployment.

Answer (score 0):

WAR deployment differs in many aspects from running the application via the Spring Boot run configuration inside the IDE. You can try to replicate all the packaging Gradle/Maven does in your run configuration e.g. via IntelliJ's artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where exactly your TLD files are when you launch the application directly from the IDE, but certainly they aren't on one of the places that the JSP specification specifies, and by default `TaglibFactory` follows the specs. But you could configure it otherwise by calling `setMetaInfTldSources` or `setClasspathTlds`. So you have to tweak the `TaglibFactory` that Spring uses; see examples of that in [Custom EL functions won't be loaded because no ObjectWarpper was specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891693/custom-el-functions-wont-be-loaded-because-no-objectwarpper-was-specified).

BTW, what `FreemarkerServlet` does (which is not used by Spring AFAIR) is that you can set the `org.freemarker.jsp.classpathTlds` and `org.freemarker.jsp.metaInfTldSources` Java system properties to do this, so that you can do these tweaks purely in the IDE launch configuration (e.g. you add `-Dorg.freemarker.jsp.metaInfTldSources=classpath` to the Java options). That's an idea you could easily re-implement.

Comment: It's not very clear what I should specify in the _setMetaInfTldSources_ method to load my custom tld and other springs that I specified in the post.

Comment: I read your original question hastily... see my comment under it. Can you add `webapp` to the runtime classpath with IntelliJ? Then `classpathTlds` could help.